# AWS ECS CloudFormation unable to create service with service discovery registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ecs

I have the following lines in my stack template:

```
Service:
        Type: AWS::ECS::Service
        DependsOn: ListenerRule
        Properties:
            LaunchType: EC2
            ServiceRegistries:
                - RegistryArn: {"Fn::GetAtt": [ServiceDiscovery, Arn]}...
ServiceDiscovery:
      Type: "AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service"
      Properties:
        Description: Service discovery registry
        DnsConfig:
          DnsRecords: [{"Type": "SRV", "TTL": 100}]
          NamespaceId:
            Fn::ImportValue: PrivateDNS
        Name: ping-service
```

Task definition network mode = "host".

When I push the template I see the following error:
`When specifying 'host' or 'bridge' for networkMode, values for 'containerName' and 'containerPort' must be specified from the task definition`

However if registry properties 'containerName' and 'containerPort' are set then it throws another error:
`Encountered unsupported property containerName`

How can service discovery registry be created with CloudFormation?

Comment: It seems that the only way for now to associate service discovery service with ECS is to use "awsvpc" network mode for task definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to specify those properties from CloudFormation yet. As seen in [the developer guide for ECS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service_definition_parameters.html) you have to specify *containerName* from the *serviceRegistries* parameter. But when we look at the [CloudFormation ServiceRegistry documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-serviceregistry.html) we can't find those options:

```
{
  "Port" : Integer,
  "RegistryArn" : String
}
```

As per this [new feature](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/aws-cloudformation-coverage-updates-for-amazon-api-gateway--amaz/), now you can specify the `containerName` and `containerPort` in the [Service Registry](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-service-serviceregistry.html).

Comment: ContainerName and ContainerPort are available now.

Answer (score 0):

I got `When specifying 'host' or 'bridge' for networkMode, values for 'containerName' and 'containerPort' must be specified from the task definition` when simply trying to create an EC2 deployment type with Host networking on an existing Service Discovery service. The fix was to create the ECS service with a Service Discovery type of "SRV" instead of "A" (the error should read more like "Service Discovery A records are not compatible with EC2 Host networking.")